# Webassets in Django

Tags: django

I am new to Webassets and i am using it together with Django. I have several questions on it and would like some help on it.. I was referring to [WebAssets in Django.](http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/webassets/django/index.html#)

Questions:

```
from django_assets import Bundle, register
js = Bundle('common/jquery.js', 'site/base.js', 'site/widgets.js',
            filters='jsmin', output='gen/packed.js')
register('js_all', js)
```

1)I understand that the Bundle helps to pac this in to packed.js but why is filters used? what is the purpose of filters here?

2) What are the uses or the advantages of using webassets? are they any tutorials/readups for webassets?

Need some guidance.. Appreciate any help...

Comment: I would recommend using django_compressor:https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/. You don't have to define your includes in settings, which is much, much better.

Comment: can u explain how it is used? like examples?

Comment: Dude - just check out the django compressor documentation; it pretty much says it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use django compressor :-)

To answer your questions however, the filter isn't the python filter you might be thinking about.  It refers to the type of compressor that's being used - e.g. closure compiler, yui compressor etc.

The idea of any asset manager is to combine, compress and version the static files (js/css and images for some asset managers) so as to optimize web page loading speed.  Using one of these asset managers - http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/asset-managers/ - leads to page load performance increase with minimal effort (usually only simple configuration is needed)